# jquery cropping image selction not returning results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made this code working but I want to have an alert , so i can see all the cordinate of x1 y1 and x2 and y2, can any one help me, the example is from this site http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/examples-callback.html#submitting-selection-coordinates-demo i have applied the code but I i dont get the cordinats, I can get the width and height tho. My code is in here http://jsfiddle.net/qzHSe/

I want to have the cordinate as a respond, I know php code will give me something but we are working with struts and java but, besides that I just want to alert the cordinate some how on the screen so I can see it myself first.

Thank you, I am very new to these things

Comment: Make that Google Analytics code some point in the relevant code?

Comment: Also, strip the irrelevant parts and post only the relevant ones please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned up some of your code and found a typo in the alert of the `selection.x1` value (you've typed `selction.x1`, missing an `e`).

http://jsfiddle.net/qzHSe/1/

Also, note that you don't have to call `$(img).imgAreaSelect()` every time you want to add more options. Just use a coma and add it like I've done.

By calling the function many times, jQuery has to do a look up in the DOM to grab the object for you to use. If you really have to call it many times, consider caching the value of the object in a variable:

```
var $img = $(img);

// now you can use $img in all your code as many times you need
// without jQuery search the DOM structure every time

$img.imgAreaSelect();

// some code
$img.attr("src", "some/path/to/image.jpg");

//some more code
$img.remove();
```

Comment: If you can, read on my improved answer to get some hints in working with jQuery.

Comment: but this gives me one cordinate when i write this

alert(selection.x1 + selection.y1 + selection.x2 + selection.y2);

Comment: If you do this, you will sum up all the coordinates. I don't got your problem.

Comment: oh I just want to get each coordinate of x and y, individually, so I guess, I do this (selection.x1 +" X1;" + selection.y1 +"Y1;" +  ..

Comment: alert( 'X1: 'selection.x1  + ";Y1:" + selection.y1 + ";X2:" + selection.x2  +";Y2:"+ selection.y2);

Comment: You are missing a + sign on the first concat: `X1:' + selection.x1`

Comment: Thank you very much got this working and under control now :P

Comment: You are welcome. The obvious always get in our way because we overlook  it.

Comment: just a question what is the use of this var $img = $(img); where would it help me?

Comment: I wish i knew javascipt as much as you did, i hate keep asking questions

Comment: As I stated in the answer, it's a good practice to cache the jQuery object in a variable if you need to use it in many places, so jQuery will not have to look the entire document for that element every time.

Comment: I'm far from expert, but I learn new things every day. Keep on reading and asking. It shows you are interested in learning.

Comment: Do you know how I can get the coordinates using Keyboard?

Comment: you can search on google on here on SO for "javascript keyboard" or "javascript hotkeys". If you have any more new questions, please open them here on SO.